How to delete a snapshot from an multipass instance
I created a second snapshot of a multipass instance and now I want to delete the first snapshot.

Please edit your question and add some details after reviewing this link. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask As written there is no info that can be used to offer any help.
